# Showing multiple checkbox, delphi

Tags: delphi, checkbox, pascal

I have 6 checkbox with edittext at each of checkbox.
I want to show only the selected checkbox with its edittext value in memo.
Here is my code:

```
//jumCheck is total of selected checkbox
for I := 0 to jumCheck - 1 do
begin
 if CheckBox1.Checked then
 begin
   Memo1.Lines.Append('Gejala: '+CheckBox1.Caption+', Penyakit: '+Edit1.Text);
 end
 else if CheckBox2.Checked then
 begin
   Memo1.Lines.Append('Gejala: '+CheckBox2.Caption+', Penyakit: '+Edit2.Text);
 end;
end;
```

And the result is just the first checkbox that i was selected for looping.

Anyone, please help me.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903132/only-one-checkbox-checked-at-a-time

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need TRadioButtons instead...

Here is the code for dynamically created TEdits and TCheckBoxes:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
      System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

    const
      ElementsCount = 6;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Memo1: TMemo;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
        chba: array [1 .. ElementsCount] of TCheckBox;
        eda: array [1 .. ElementsCount] of TEdit;
        procedure CBClick(Sender: TObject);
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i: byte;
    begin
      for i := 1 to ElementsCount do
      begin
        chba[i] := TCheckBox.Create(self);
        chba[i].Tag := i; //you can change the code of CBClick
                          //and know out the sender easier by Tag property
        chba[i].Top := (i - 1) * 30 + 1;
        chba[i].Left := 1;
        chba[i].Caption := 'Some caption ' + inttostr(i);
        chba[i].Parent := self;
        chba[i].OnClick:= CBClick;

        eda[i] := TEdit.Create(self);
        eda[i].Top := (i - 1) * 30 + 1;
        eda[i].Left := 100;
        eda[i].Text := '';
        eda[i].Parent := self;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.CBClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i: byte;
    begin
      Memo1.Text := '';
      for i := 1 to ElementsCount do
      begin
        if chba[i].Checked then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Append(chba[i].Caption + ' ' + eda[i].Text);
          exit;//??? In this case only the first checked will be processed
               //Probably, you need TRadioButton's instead
        end;
      end;
    end;

    end.
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a few problems:

- Using `else` skips all checkboxes after the first selected checkbox
- There is no point in combining `for` and a list of `if`-statements. If you have a `if`-statement for every checkbox, what do you want to iterate with the `for` over?
- Your `for` starts with 0, but the first checkbox seems to be CheckBox1 (generally it would be better to use more descriptive names)

What you seem to be looking for is the method `FindComponent` to find a component of a certain name or index.

E.g. it becomes

```
for I := 1 to jumCheck  do
begin
 if (FindComponent('CheckBox' + IntToStr(i)) as TCheckBox).Checked then
 begin
   Memo1.Lines.Append('Gejala: '+(FindComponent('CheckBox' + IntToStr(i)) as TCheckBox).Caption+', Penyakit: '+(FindComponent('Edit' + IntToStr(i)) as TEdit).Text);
 end
end;
```

Comment: FindComponent isn't great. Better to use arrays that you populate in code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When all the checkboxes are unchecked, he does not need an array of edits

Comment: You don't understand me. Instead of calling `FindComponent` you write `CheckBox[i]` or `Edit[i]`, or even better, you have a record containing a pair of controls (check box and edit), and an array of those records. The idea is that you don't call `FindComponent`.

Comment: You do not call FindComponent for the edits, when the checkboxes are all unchecked

Comment: I recommend not calling `FindComponent` at all. I know that I make a point of never doing so.

Comment: @BeniBela The main reason why David Heffernan is disadvising the use of `FindComponent` is because `FindComponent` is searching by name amongst all client components regardless of their type. So for instance if in your case you would have some other component named CheckBox1 for instance the `FindComponent` would return you the handle of that component and you would be typecasting it to TCheckBox class type. I hope you know that it will lead to data damage if you are trying to access some object using wrong class interface.

Comment: @BeniBela So your suggested approach is a potentionally very dangerous code which can potentially lead to some nasty and very hard to track bugs. Sure you are probably thinking to yourself "Why would I go and name some other component besides check box as CheckBox1?" Well normally you would not. But you could. And one of the toughest jobs of us programmers is trying to predict all corner cases. Besides storing checkboxes in a separate list would allow you much faster iteration through them since you will be iteration only through them and not through all child components.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That is not how it works. `as` is type safe casting. It would raise an exception, it does not cause data corruption.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used FindComponent without any issues on computers with 166 MHz CPU. If it was fast enough then, it is fast enough nowadays

Comment: It's not an issue of speed. The performance won't be a problem here. It's one of clarity. I'd always opt for static type safety in a scenario like this. It's easy to achieve and makes the code much cleaner. I like having the compiler find errors rather than waiting until runtime. Which might be too late.